# limiting the length of a string

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string that says `15:00:00` how can I limit the length of the string so it says `15:00` ?

Comment: i think your question is not clear.and refresh it

Comment: Limit it while taking input from user or limit it for the purpose of application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dates

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
sd.format(date); //will return formatted date
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
String time = "15:00:00";
time = time.subString(0,time.lastIndexOf(":"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String time = "15:00:00";
String str =time.substring(0,result.length() - 3);
```